# Python requests downloads HTML if file is not found

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I am downloading a list of remote files. My code looks like the following:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
    total_length = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])

    if total_length:
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()

except (requests.RequestException, StandardError):
    pass
```

My problem is that requests downloads plain HTML for files that do not exist (for example the 404 page, or other similar in nature HTML pages). Is there a way to circumvent this? Any header to check like `Content-Type` perhaps?

**Solution:**

I used the `r.raise_for_status()` function call as per the accepted answer and also added an extra check for `Content-Type` like:

```
if r.headers['Content-Type'].split('/')[0] == "text":
    #pass/raise here
```

(MIME types list here: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `r.raise_for_status()` to raise an exception for responses with 4xx and 5xx status codes, or test the `r.status_code` explicitly.

[`r.raise_for_status()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) raises an `HTTPError` exception, which is a subclass of `RequestException` which you already catch:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
    r.raise_for_status()  # raises if not a 2xx or 3xx response
    total_length = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])

    if total_length:
        # etc.    
except (requests.RequestException, StandardError):
    pass
```

The `r.status_code` check would let you narrow down what you consider a proper response code. Do note that `3xx` redirects are handled automatically, and you won't see other 3xx responses as `requests` won't send conditional requests in this case, so there is little need for explicit tests here. But if you do, it'd look something like:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
r.raise_for_status()  # raises if not a 2xx or 3xx response
total_length = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])

if 200 <= r.status_code < 300 and total_length:
    # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! I also added an extra check for content type (if not text/*).

Answer (score 1):

```
if r.status_code == 404:
    handle404()
else:
    download()
```